# Where in clause in Flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to use where in clasue but i get this error:

> Invalid argument [1, 2, 3] with type List  Only num, String and
> Uint8List are supported.

My code:

```
Database db = await instance.database;
List<Map> maps = await db.query('table',
where: 'categoryID in (?)', whereArgs: [ [1,2,3]]);
```

From this [document](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/sql.md)

> Particulary, lists (expect for blob content) are not supported. A
> common mistake is to expect to use IN (?) and give a list of values.
> This does not work. Instead you should list each argument one by one:

```
var list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name IN (?, ?, ?)', ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']);
```

But my categories can change any moment so I cant list each argument one by one.

Answer (score 12):

While I understand that it could sound painful, that is unfortunately the way SQLite works and sqflite does not do any SQL parsing.

You could try the following solution that I personnaly use to build the proper number of `?`.

```
List.filled(inArgsCount, '?').join(',')
```

For example:

```dart
var inArgs = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish'];
var list = await db.query('my_table',
    where: 'name IN (${List.filled(inArgs.length, '?').join(',')})',
    whereArgs: inArgs);
```

Comment: can i do that with list<String>? not vector?